# Частичное отображение следующей вкладки с помощью TabLayout

Tags: android, android-sdk, ui, swipe, android-tablayout

В моем проекте есть экран с TabLayout и тремя вкладками. Между ними можно переключаться свайпом влево-вправо. Вот так, например:

```
scrollpay.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(PayActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft()
        {
            selectorTable.getTabAt(1).select();
        }
    });
```

Я хочу, чтобы в начале срабатывания алгоритма свайпа, отобразилась часть соседней вкладки таблицы, чтобы показать пользователю, что при продолжении жеста произойдет переключение на соседнюю вкладку, как это выглядит на прикрепленном изображении (сделан в фотошопе из двух разных скриншотов). Примерно так же, как вытаскивается иконка обновления у SwipeRefreshLayout. Как я могу это сделать?

[image: Вот так это выглядит]

Comment: Так оно же вроде из коробки так работает, нет?  Или вы хотите другой эффект получить?

Comment: В том то и дело, что не работает. Сразу переключает, без предпросмотра. Как сделать так, чтобы работало? Изображение, кстати, в фотошопе сделано из двух вкладок, это не скриншот.

Comment: А что вы делаете в слушателе? selectorTable - это список вкладок сверху? Что будет, если убрать слушатель?

Comment: Да, это TabLayout сверху. OnSwipeTouchListener - это самописный слушатель свайпа, если его убрать - то свайп соответственно не будет работать. Возможно есть какой-то другой класс для отслеживания алгоритма свайпа, который уже поддерживает такую функциональность?

Comment: Код класса OnSwipeTouchListener здесь: https://pastebin.com/UL950A7k

Comment: Зачем вам реализовывать свой ловец жестов? добавляете ViewPager на активити, ставите ему адаптер выдающий фрагменты по номеру страницы. Этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: А где можно посмотреть пример кода?

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html